# Error setting DisplayGroup in Form ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form

I'm trying to add an `addDisplayGroup` to my form, but I'm getting the following error:

> "Call to undefined method Application\Form\MyForm::addDisplayGroup()"

Here is my form code:

```
namespace Application\Form;
use Zend\Form\Form;
class MyForm extends Form {


public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct('Myform-form');
    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
    $this->addElements();
    $this->addInputFilter();
}

private function addElements() {
    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'name' => 'first_name',
        'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'first_name'
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'First Name: ',
        ),

    ));
    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'name' => 'last_name',
        'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'last_name'
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Last Name: ',
        ),
    ));

    $this->addDisplayGroup(array('first_name', 'last_name'), 'information');

}
}
```

Comment: What's "DisplayGroup"? I'm not sure that's a concept in Zend\Form. Do you mean ValidationGroup? Are you looking for the Fieldset concept? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm looking for the Fieldset concept. I want to create virtual groupings of those two elements for display purposes. According to the documentation on zend http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.displaygroups  I'm doing the right thing, but I'm wondering why I got that error message.

Comment: The manual you posted is for ZF1. The code you posted is ZF2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create an **Zend\Form\Fieldset**

Like this: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html#creating-fieldsets

And after, using like this: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html#the-form-element